# Why despite installing the same code, different devices return different order of the same set from the HD

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsfilemanager, nsbundle

I have two devices iPhone and Ipad

When the iPad is connected the array in which these .png files are retrieved from the HD and stored will contain the Files in the following order for example even if the code executed for several times
1, 3, 5, 8,11,25, 66, 2. These are just file names

When iPhone is connected, given the same set of images on HD, when the code is executed the array contains images in the following order for example;
11 5 25 1 2 66 3 8

Please let me know why despite  the same code both devices differ in the order in which they applying data retrieval from the HD.

Comment: kindly add the code as well.

Comment: you can sort according to any parameter or name wise then display. it will work in . both the cases.

Comment: You asked this question previously but did not show any code, despite a request to do so.  Please show the code you are using to retrieve the images. You may be using a set or dictionary, which are unordered

Answer (score 0):

you can sort according to any parameter or name wise then display. it will work in  both the cases.

some demo code

```
let fm = FileManager.default
let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath!
let items = try! fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: path)
var sortItems : [Any]?
for item in items {
    // sort algo
    sortItems.append(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know why despite the same code both devices differ in the order in which they applying data retrieval from the HD.

The documentation for `contentsOfDirectory` states:

> The order of the files in the returned array is undefined.

At least the (version of the) particular file system (HFS+, APFS, FAT) and the order of creation of items can effect the order of the returned items.

If you need the items in a consistent order sort the returned array according to the order you require.

HTH